# Difference between Zero speed and Near zero speed geartooth sensor

Tags: proximity-sensor

I would like to ask what is practical difference between geartooth speed sensor which is able to detect zero speed and near zero speed movements.

What is zero speed in this case?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero speed is 'what position is the gear wheel in now?' You would need optical or Hall sensors to do something like this.

A dynamic sensor could be something simpler like a coil of wire sensing the change in field as a tooth goes past a magnet. Obviously when that setup is stationary, no voltage is generated regardless of the static position of the gear wheel.